# Load style and script for custom post type metabox

Tags: php, custom-post-types, plugin-development

I'm using this code to try loading some custom assets for a custom post type I have registered

```php
    public function setup_theme_backend_assets($hook)
    {
        $screen = get_current_screen();        
        if( in_array( $hook, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) ){
            if( is_object( $screen ) && 'store-locator' == $screen->post_type ){
                wp_register_script(
                    'map',
                    'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js',
                    [],
                    false,
                    true
                );
                wp_enqueue_script('map');

                wp_register_script( 
                    'map-config', 
                    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/inc/leaflet-map.js', 
                    [], 
                    false, 
                    true 
                );
                wp_enqueue_script('map-config');

                wp_register_style(
                    'map',
                    'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css',
                    false
                );
                wp_enqueue_style('map');
            }
        }
    }
```

To call the function into the class construct I'm using this hook

```php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'setup_theme_backend_assets']);
```

I've noticed using the chrome dev tools that the assets aren't loaded, is there something wrong into my function?

Comment: as an aside, I would avoid using the CDN's for leaflet, as it's a privacy and performance problem! In the old days when you used a CDN for a library it would allow you to make an extra connection to speed it up, then cache it for all sites, but modern browsers have independent caches for every site so there's no speed up, and it's a performance hit as you can't use HTTP2 parallel transfers to download the file either

Comment: @ICTDEV, I don't think this will work - `$hook != 'edit.php?post_type=store-locator'` - because the value of that `$hook` is likely `edit.php` regardless the current post type. So maybe you would want to use `if ( 'edit-store-locator' !== get_current_screen()->id )` instead.

Comment: @SallyCJ ok, need to test, as I write into another comment, I'm trying to load leaflet map inside a metabox of a custom post type

Comment: If you're trying to target the post editing screen (e.g. at `wp-admin/post.php`), then that `edit-store-locator` would be `store-locator`. But the point here is check the current screen ID.

Comment: @SallyCJ ok, I've noticed that I had a typo also into the code, now I'm able to see that the css of leaflet is loaded, but the js files ssems not present and no map will be displayed. Need to fix this

Comment: Are you sure the script tags are not in the source? Are there any errors in the console? Because I'm guessing your `leaflet-map.js` needs the `leaflet.js` as its dependency, i.e. use `[ 'map' ]`.

Comment: probably I've missed the dependency, I need to test by adding the `leaflet` into the dependency array

Comment: are you sure that your enqueue functions even run? It could be that your `if` checks are resolving to `false` not `true` on those pages. How is this function called and where is the hook added? And where is the object created/used? In a plugin/template/theme? Other than checking the frontend have you confirmed that all parts of the code execute on the server by checking directly? This could be via debug breakpoints or even via a `wp_die` placed in the code if you want to do it oldschool. Also you should definitely declare the dependency or the order it's printed may not be correct

Comment: @TomJNowell as Sally CJ suggested, I've added the dependency and now the map is loaded. The problem was with the dependency and with the `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` function, I've noticed into console that I need to remove the `inc` from the path, because the plugin file is already into the same directory where I have the other files

Comment: can one of you post that as an answer below so that people don't turn up and try to solve it from scratch?

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you all for the help, I will accept the answer if it will be posted.